# Make $ionicPopup behave like a modal (catch click events of backdrop)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using `$ionicPopup.confirm()` in a list to ask whether to delete the row or not.

Unfortunately a second popup opens if the user ignores the popup and taps on another Delete-icon. Then only a reload of the app helps, since the first popup stays open and isn't closable.

Is there a way to lock the backdrop so no clicks come through to the underlying page while popup is open?

(Using ionic v1.0.1)

**Code**

controller:

```
this.deleteModule = function (index, item) {
    return $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: $translate.instant('moduleplan.deleteModuleTitle'),
        template: $translate.instant('moduleplan.deleteModuleText'),
        cancelText: $translate.instant('moduleplan.deleteModuleCancel'),
        okText: $translate.instant('moduleplan.deleteModuleOk')
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
            return deleteModule(item.id);
        }
    });
};
```

view (shortened):

```
<ion-content scroll="true">
    <ion-list type="list-inset"
        show-delete="monthCtrl.isEditing"
        show-reorder="monthCtrl.isEditing">
        <ion-item class="item-timeline"
            ng-repeat="module in monthCtrl.modules track by $index"
            option-sort
            option-sort-disabled="monthCtrl.optionSortDisabled(module)">

            <!-- some content -->

            <ion-delete-button
                class="ion-minus-circled"
                ng-click="monthCtrl.deleteModule($index, module)"
                ng-hide="monthCtrl.optionDeleteDisabled(module)">
            </ion-delete-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Edit**

While popup is opened, when I click on other buttons, they don't react (and in browser the cursor does not change to hand).

Analyzing one of the delete-buttons in the DOM:

```
<div class="item-left-edit item-delete enable-pointer-events visible active">
  <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled button icon button-icon" ng-click="monthCtrl.deleteModule($index, module)" ng-hide="monthCtrl.optionDeleteDisabled(module)">
  </ion-delete-button>
</div>
```

When I remove `enable-pointer-events` class from `div.item-delete`, then hovering the element doesn't show hand and the delete-buttons are not clickable => no second popup is opened.

- `enable-pointer-events` is defined by `{ pointer-events: auto; }`.
- `div.popup-container` has z-index: 12
- `div.item-delete` has z-index: 0
- `ion-item` has computed z-index: 2
- found a few other z-index, but the sibling near backdrop (z-index: 11) and popup-container (z-index: 12) containing my list has only z-index: 2.

Comment: that is weird. Because pop up by default have backdrop. can you share code how you are using it?

Comment: hmm...try one thing, click anywhere else(not on other delete button) out of popup.What happens?

Comment: @mudasserajaz explanation added.